# Image selected from Camera Roll shows up as black screen

Tags: codenameone

This issue seems to have just started in the last day.

I have code to open gallery, store image and show it. If the image is too large (seems to be anything over 130000bytes) it just shows a black screen. Here is my code:

```
String path = (String) ev.getSource();
InputStream stream = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(path);

OutputStream out = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + movePath);
Util.copy(stream, out);

Image image = Image.createImage(path);
ScaleImageLabel fillLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(image);
fillLabel.setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL);
imageVideoContainer.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, fillLabel);
```

Like I said, I'm sure this was working last time I built it just a few days ago. Has anything changed in 3.5 that could have affected this? Only seems to be happening on iOS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If this was any other point in time I would have needed to investigate. However, since we are in the code freeze of 3.5 which we just exited we haven't done server updates for the week since July 27th 2016 to August 5th (this coming Friday).

So I doubt it's a change in the way we process the image.

There are several things that might be the cause of something like this:

1. OS update broke something.
2. This was always broken but hard to notice due to minor changes in reproduction.
3. We made a change and the last good build was more than a week ago.

I can't tell if it's 1 so let's check 3 and 2. For 3 lets look at the commit history:
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commits/master

Notice that changes that were committed today (August 3rd 2016) aren't yet in the build servers anyway...

Looking thru the code the only thing that looks moderately suspect is the getRGB changes but that code isn't reached from the calls you made. Notice that you can usually use [versioned build](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---get-repeatable-builds-build-against-a-consistent-version-of-codename-one-use-the-versioning-feature.html) and build against 3.4 to verify that this isn't a regression in our code but I'm not sure if `ScaledImageLabel` existed in 3.4.

So let's assume this is 2, that something was broken before. Since you are grabbing a picture from the camera roll you might have a VERY high resolution image. To prove that this is a problem try this:

```
ScaleImageLabel fillLabel = new ScaleImageLabel(image.scaledWidth(300));
```

Assuming that works this probably means the image size (width/height) exceeds GPU limits on the device. This is something you can solve by having a slightly smaller image to begin with e.g. instead of copying the image you can use `ImageIO.save` that will scale said image beforehand.

Comment: I tried scaling it and it still didn't help. I confirmed that it was only happening for the high resolution photos though. And it really doesn't seem to be happening in my app that was built a week ago. Maybe I changed something I couldn't find. Anyway, using ImageIO.save to save a smaller version and then use that for display has worked so that's ok. Also, version 3.4 isn't available for me to build against? Thanks.

Comment: You can select version 3.4 once you login with a pro account using the login button.

Comment: Eclipse is only giving me up to version 3.3, then it goes to Latest

Comment: Do you have an old version of the plugin? Also check out in the new Codename One settings UI: Right click the project -> Codename One -> Codename One Settings. See this: http://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-preferences-command-state-localization-locking.html